# How to make docker-credential-pass be accessible by another user on the system?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have installed gitlab-runner which by default creates the user **gitlab-runner** on the system and add it to **docker** group. I have decided to try to **docker login** from **gitlab-runner** shell account to investigate the reason of why I am getting error regarding login on my pipeline. I have noticed that when trying to logout my default user **freshuser** from the the whole system via the GUI and login with **gitlab-runner** user it works and it prompts me to write a passphrase but when I am on the default system user **freshuser** I don't get the passphrase prompt for the docker-credential-pass helper. So I tried to login and it stored the password. The same thing when I wanted to create the key for storing docker login creds with **GnuPG** the password prompt won't show up only when I login with **gitlab-runner**. Notice this happens too when pushing to container registry. Can anyone tell me what's going on I am confused?

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 79, in _execute
    output = subprocess.check_output(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/docker-credential-pass', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 264, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
    data = store.get(registry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 35, in get
    data = self._execute('get', server)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 93, in _execute
    raise errors.process_store_error(e, self.program)
docker.credentials.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-pass exited with "exit status 2: gpg: decryption failed: No secret key".
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 203, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/metrics/decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 862, in push
    self.project.push(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 828, in push
    service.push(ignore_push_failures)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 1260, in push
    output = self.client.push(repo, tag=tag, stream=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 480, in push
    header = auth.get_config_header(self, registry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 47, in get_config_header
    authcfg = resolve_authconfig(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 324, in resolve_authconfig
    return authconfig.resolve
_authconfig(registry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 235, in resolve_authconfig
    cfg = self._resolve_authconfig_credstore(registry, store_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 280, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
    raise errors.DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-pass exited with "exit status 2: gpg: decryption failed: No secret key".')
```

UPDATE: I have tried to add the user **gitlab-runner** to the default system user group but still no luck.

Passphrase prompt that I get when system logged in from **gitlab-runner** account:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found answer from here I had to add the **gitlab-runner** to control list to be able to use the display:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/654966/enable-x-display-access-for-local-user